# Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.04 very slow on surface

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, cuda, microsoft, surface

I have recently installed ubuntu on Surfacebook 2 (1793). The laptop comes with Geforce GTX 1060 Mobile, an intel uhd620, 16gb of rams and 512 gb ssd.
After I install cuda and nvidia toolkits, the computer is very slow, especially for mouse movement. The mouse movement is laggy and unstable. After searching on the internet, someone suggested upgrade to later version so I update to 19.04 but the behavior is the same.
 I am wondering if anyone has some ideas about what could possibly be the cause of this issue and could provide some suggestion on how to resolve this?

(I have installed Ubuntu on other laptops such as thinkpad or dell xps and has never experienced such issue

Comment: $2500 Laptop? Wow....Maybe Microsoft won't allow other software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for anyone who has the same issue, the problem is that the kernel comes with ubuntu is not fully compatible with surface book2:

- lacking drivers for touch screen
- deffective behaviors for mouse movement.
- cannot suspend/hibernate.
- etc. 
  The solution for me is to install a jakeday's linux kernel for surface products. The instruction can be found here:

https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface
After installing this kernel, my machine seems to be working ok.

Comment: Probably add a disclaimer that this is not a good thing to do? I'd hate to see a kid brick his Surface 2

Comment: Thanks for this info @hieu-le. Dual boot turned out to be a great thing to do. Didn't even brick my Surface 2!